# How to add stackpanel to menuflyoutitem in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

[image: I need this type of flyout]how to add stackpanel as menuflyoutitem in UWP?
what i have tried is?
menuflyoutitem.content=stackpanel;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MenuFlyoutItem` does not support complex layouts. If you want to place multiple elements with the help of `StackPanel`, please use `Flyout`.

```xml
<Flyout x:Name="TestFlyout">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- other code -->
    </StackPanel>
</Flyout>
```

---

**Update**

If you want to display the picture icon, you can use `BitmapIcon`:

```xml
<MenuFlyout x:Name="TestFlyout">
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Merge">
        <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
            <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/your_image.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>
        </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
    </MenuFlyoutItem>
</MenuFlyout>
```

Comment: i had update the question...i need flyout like the picture i had added.FlyoutItem with two UIelement one is image and the other is text.

Comment: Hi @PremKumarShanmugam I update my answer, please check

Comment: it work fine...but there is some problem.i had use .png format image,the image is a colored image.but it shows only black color image.

Comment: If you want to show colored icons, you can set `BitmapIcon.ShowAsMonochrome` to `False`